# Shortcut/hotkey to open/jump/navigate to function definition in VBA editor

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I am in Formula bar and my cursor is inside the name of a function, is there any way I could use a hotkey/shortcut to jump to the function definition in VBA editor so that I could check out the details of the function implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can press the shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

This will jump to the definition of the procedure or function.

Answer (score 0):

Definition? Do you mean arguments/syntax? Why not just include it in your UDF (User-Defined Function) so it shows a tooltip?

> Professional Excel Development by Stephen Bullen:

```
Function IFERROR(ByRef ToEvaluate As Variant, ByRef Default As Variant) As Variant 
    If IsError(ToEvaluate) Then 
        IFERROR = Default 
    Else 
        IFERROR = ToEvaluate 
    End If 
End Function 

Sub RegisterUDF() 
    Dim s As String 
    s = "Provides a shortcut replacement for the common worksheet construct" & vbLf _ 
    & "IF(ISERROR(<expression>, <default>, <expression>)" 

    Application.MacroOptions macro:="IFERROR", Description:=s, Category:=9 
End Sub 

Sub UnregisterUDF() 
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="IFERROR", Description:=Empty, Category:=Empty 
End Sub
```

[source](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=78123)

You can also hit <kbd>ctrl shift A</kbd> after you you begin your `=formula(` to bring up syntax.

Comment: Thanks Raystafarian for your advice.  Sorry I did not speak clearly enough.  When I am in Formula bar and my cursor is inside the name of a function, I would like to use a hotkey/shortcut to jump to the function definition in VBA editor so that I could check out the details of the function implementation.

Comment: You could leave the VBA editor open and  `alt tab` to it..

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but even I have the VBA editor open, when I press alt tab, I always get the Windows Application Switch popup rather than my cursor jumps to the function definition in VBA editor.